# Unlock field if checkbox is checked. VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Good day, I'm having a problem with my little app. I want to unlock field if checkbox next to it is selected and save this value to array, but when i click checkbox my field doesn't unlock. Here is my code:

```
  <ul>
    <li v-for="oneFragrance in fragrance" v-bind:key="oneFragrance.id">
      <input type="checkbox" :value="oneFragrance.nameOfFragrance" :id="oneFragrance.id" v-model="checkedComponents"> {{oneFragrance.nameOfFragrance}}
      <input type="text"  :disabled="checkedComponents" v-model="valuesOfComponents">
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: By click on the checkbox I think you mean check it, so the _checkedComponents_ is true and that disable your input because = _:disabled="checkedComponents"_, maybe you just need to add a ! not before checkedComponents =>  _:disabled="!checkedComponents"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul>
<li v-for="(oneFragrance , index) in fragrance" v-bind:key="oneFragrance.id">
  <input type="checkbox" :value="oneFragrance.nameOfFragrance" :id="oneFragrance.id" v-model="checkedComponents[index]"> {{oneFragrance.nameOfFragrance}}
  <input type="text"  :disabled="checkedComponents[index]" v-model="valuesOfComponents">
</li>
```

in your data

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checkedComponents: []
  }
})
```

Comment: Yo, thank u man very much. But I found also 1 mistake in my code. When u enter data to input this data was duplicated to all inputs. But i found solution. All u need to do is change v-model="valuesOfComponents" => v-model="valuesOfComponents[index]". Thanks one more time!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the v-model of the first input to a :click

```
 <ul>
<li v-for="oneFragrance in fragrance" v-bind:key="oneFragrance.id">
  <input type="checkbox" :value="oneFragrance.nameOfFragrance" :id="oneFragrance.id" :click="checkedComponents = !checkedComponents"> {{oneFragrance.nameOfFragrance}}
  <input type="text"  :disabled="checkedComponents" v-model="valuesOfComponents">
</li>
```

this way the value should always change and the text input should unlock

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox has to save a value in an array, try this:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="oneFragrance in fragrance" v-bind:key="oneFragrance.id">
    <input type="checkbox" :value="oneFragrance.nameOfFragrance" :id="oneFragrance.id" v-model="checkedComponents"> {{oneFragrance.nameOfFragrance}}
    <input type="text"  :disabled="!checkedComponents.includes(oneFragrance.nameOfFragrance)" v-model="valuesOfComponents">
    </li>
</ul>
```

And you need to set `checkedComponents: []` in your data() function